# How to install and use a python library

Tags: python

I'm trying to control a stepper motor with this library:

https://pypi.org/project/RPistepper/

After success `pip install RPistepper` and run:

```
import RPistepper as stp
```

The IDE (Thonny) show me this error:

```
no module named "RPistepper"
```

python 2.7.16

I'm in the very beginning with python. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thonny uses Python3.

Install RPiStepper under Python3 with:

```
pip3 install RPiStepper
```